# Hooking Outlook, privileges issue

Tags: c++, outlook

I'm capturing some Outlook events using a MFC application. The problem is that I can't write data into a file unless I'm running both Outlook and my App as an administrator. How can I solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And where is that file located? If you cannot write that to that file unless you an admin, that means Outlook also needs to run as an admin otherwise you cannot connect to it due to different security contexts.

Can you split your app in two? The first one (it can be an Outlook addin) writes the file in a user accessible folder. The second app (running as an admin), picks the file from the user accessible directory and copies/modifies the file in the restricted directory.

Comment: I agree with you, however I have a thread that hooks sync events and writes to the same directory : this thread is able to write even if I run both Outlook and my app with user account. 
The main thread, which hooks app events, can't write to that directory unless I'm running both apps as an admin. That's what cnfuses me!

Comment: When you say you cannot write data to the folder, which function call exactly fails? What is the error?